# How to output a value stored in a variable in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I am learning assembly programming using "8086 emu" (Its a software program . Emulator .) I am evaluating a basic expression -

**a=b+c-d*e**

My problem is that when I am using int 21h to take in values , Its taking only single digit (character) as input for each variable .

Also after the evaluation , I am **unable to print the value stored in the variable 'a' on the output screen** .

Can anyone give a solution for both the problems ?

Comment: You're probably more in need of a tutorial on x86 programming rather than an answer on a Q&A site. Something like [this](http://muruganad.com/8086/8086-assembly-language-read-a-string-using-standard-input-keyboard.html) may be a good place to start.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of assembly.  No handholding here.  If you need it, you bring it.  Just like a trip to the South Pole or the Moon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part (reading in a string until a sentinel key, e.g. the enter key is hit), you'll write a loop to do that.

A function for parsing the ASCII decimal string into a register value is also needed.

For printing to screen, you'll need:

- Either `int 21h, AH = 02h` ( http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm ) one character at a time
- Or `int 21h, AH = 09h` ( http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm ) one whole string

You'll also need an itoa function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) to convert a register value into a multi-digit ASCII string.

The URLs is part of an assembly programming tutorial called Ralf Brown's Interrupt List (RBIL).

Comment: the **itoa** function was what I exactly needed to know . Thats the exact solution to my second problem . Thanks :)  The solution to the first problem , though is not that clear , is enough to give me a good idea about how I should proceed . :)

Answer (score 0):

For one byte values I've used to convert it to string and use bios function...
It used to be something like this:

```
 mov ah, 0
 mov al, ds:["yourvalueaddress"]
 mov di, 100 ;temporary string address
 mov cx, 0
 cmp ax, 0
 jge label1
 mov bl, 45
 mov ds:[di], bl
 add di, 1
 neg ax
 label1:
 mov bx, 10
 label2:
 add cx, 1
 mov dx, 0
 idiv bx
 push dx
 cmp ax, 0
 jne label2
 label3:
 pop dx
 add dx, 30h
 mov ds:[di], dl
 add di, 1
 add cx, -1
 cmp cx, 0
 jne label3:
 mov dl, 24h            ;ENDL
 mov ds:[di], dl        
 mov dx, 100         ;100 => temporary string address
 mov ah, 09h
 int 21h
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you took :)